# Digital circuit that squares a 4-bit input

Tags: digital-logic, identification, reference-materials

Many years ago, I found a digital circuit that squares a 4-bit input in an old textbook (perhaps 1970s or 1980s, possibly older).
(The figure below is not the original figure.
I think the figure below differs from the original in that it has been rotated 90 degrees.)
I do not have access to that textbook any more and I do not have additional details about the textbook.

Have you seen this circuit before?
If so, could you give me the name and author of the source?
I am using this figure in my teaching and I would like to properly cite the source.

[image: Squarer]

Comment: In passing, found this paper which might interest you https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/29f0/132fbbc51ef05c2f1c9e732cafe93286160d.pdf

Comment: And United States Patent RE35365 from 1996 http://www.freepatentsonline.com/RE35365.pdf and 5,629,885 from 1997 https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/70/87/c7/7dd3a18b9b2882/US5629885.pdf

Comment: the schematic may have originated from a device datasheet

Comment: @jonathanjo, thank you for the links.  I'm not familiar with them, and they look very useful.

Comment: @jsotola, if you find a data sheet that has this circuit, then please add it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A derivation instead of an identification:

```
bit-wise partial products:                  A₃A₀         A₂A₀  A₁A₀ A₀A₀
                                A₃A₁        A₀A₃         A₀A₂  A₀A₁
                  A₃A₂          A₁A₃        A₂A₁         A₁A₁
     A₃A₃         A₂A₃          A₂A₂        A₁A₂
simplification:                                                   0  A₀
                                A₃A₀        A₂A₀         A₀A₁
     A₃A₂         A₃A₁          A₂A₁                      A₁
      A₃                         A₂
```

circuit (from Q):
[image: horizontal 4-bit squarer]

7400-series implementation:
As sketched, 2×'08, 3×'183 for lack of half-adders. Or 2×'183, 1×'86, same total of 5×14 pin.

More likely to be around would be '(2)83 4-bit adders.
Without a *carry in*, you can use "same significance 2<sup>k</sup>" inputs Ak and Bk "as an *and* gate":
There will be a *carry out* (to k+1) iff both are true.
Pulling off this trick twice reduces the BOM to 1×'08, 2×'283 for a total of 46 pins.

(Better presentation options than [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKswA50HYEDZICZUBmLbNQkBSCiqhAUwFowwAoAGRGzwBYQBObJx4huqKOBAAzAIYAbAM51qkFmEojCecGC3dN4DIKpakCFgHchvAVZCaqKgLIib3MIO6vR4vNDMcEPi1UWiCRMSoIGQUlJBUObjhOXkSqb0ipOUVldnFsXjSIiWjsuIsRbxsuayMWAA9OZhA8LXzjJF5hAA0VBoQMPmbWyDE8DubeLtYGwlRBPHI3JDwPCZAuvHqQJk6tNWbx7sItxLE1DxxwQJFmqg2e8qp88RsVNVoCbRNPsEMfajMfTOCCQYEggjUYk6d0IGy2aj2CFGSXcEGh61hrEsgWCtG4vBCUHKCB0XwopOeKks+LOpJp-FqDWw+ncT0J7kWt3WkAefUgoP6FAQ5FZNzwdzwU3KbghdPcySJ2PxZIQysJb3U7NJ7L+xgBqnUv1lez+Rv+pnKz2YrRqivAuAZCtelttVGdljAYWt4DClPKnptIiSfuplXmGC07ooYXs0dxdr0WljiYMtWxPz+CE+sapQaoyeDBVUNnlhCzZLLukgfCh0qSMrs2Ch8tz4tG6Eb7Yi5UITZEpb7BG7lkJsZ1adTdnFk7NufzkAKjtzDeeJMDbxsvbElbsqF4O8SNZEuWwl0IC84lyH4ioJViCc305xU4cLGcWebgg-FSKvjMzmqF9bHpYw-DfCg-hTfoPHSZowOcbwG0Q2C-3A70G3QlD4PAZUMNwrD-0nDDIII8o2yA8jr3iOwL1jOjpwcTIYhyalniQtj9GXDik3LFNcwPfQd3PItLCEi8eHnESJkk6SgNbCNHTwBSc39ZVhJw-cGNyb1Yx0bcGPEO8WMvQRY1PDwW0tS4G2g-sJ1smzIM46VnmTVyL1zHB8yfB11NzcygICvyXP3C8vJoqTwvUoKPMeCLwni3MwDUi9vGC6l9MKRLpXlNjCztUVvVFKMS1JGx1XKcq8QJV8GggNQOkGSExRhLpjhmZUGrsL0kRa9ZJU2IA)?)

The MSB of the square is just the AND of both most significant input bits.
Bit S₂ is somewhat simple: A1¬A0, but those middle bits are just too complicated for (me to find a?) slick '7400 implementation.

Comment: ("the two 4-bit adder solution" sort of uses 16 half adders where the "original" uses 9. Oh well.)